failed to load driver iris and failed to open swrast 24.04 lts
I was using pygame to make a tic tac toe game but i always run into this error.
pygame 2.5.2 (SDL 2.28.2, Python 3.11.7)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
failed to load driver: iris
MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  163
  Current serial number in output stream:  164


Are you using Ubuntu? Which version? This might be a better fit for a programming site.
